# Linux workstation and Active Directory authentication

Tags: linux, domain-controller, directory, windows-authentication

I read a few articles regarding "How to Authenticate Linux Clients with Microsoft Active Directory"

My question before I do it: what will happen to Notebooks that try to login when the Active directory server is not available?

It's not an issue with a Windows Notebook, but I don't have a clue regarding Linux.
I have Ubuntu and Fedora Notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

I am note sure if this works for AD as well, but for a plain LDAP server you can use libpam_ccreds  (for "cached credentials") to achieve what you want.

This will store the credentials on the system so it still works in disconnected mode.

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PamCcredsHowto) is a tutorial that explains how to use it on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm just wondering how it will work while you connect AD as LDAP. This may be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Also when you are connecting to AD using samba/winbind you can also add it in smb.conf

```
winbind offline logon = yes
```

Remeber to add `cached_login = yes` to `/etc/security/pam_winbind.conf` while you are using `winbind offline logon = yes`.

Comment: Please let me know how it goes.